# JavaFX how to hide empty column cell in tableView

Tags: css, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I am using a tableView with UNCONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY.
And I want set all empty column cell to white background.

This is the current view.

[image]

I am trying to search the empty node, but I can't find it even if I search all the nodes contained in tableView by following code (test function):

```
 private void test() {
        ArrayList<Node> nodes = getAllNodes(tableView);
        nodes.forEach(node -> {
            if(node instanceof TableCell) {
                if(((TableCell) node).getText() == null || ((TableCell) node).getText().isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println(true);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static ArrayList<Node> getAllNodes(Parent root) {
        ArrayList<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
        addAllDescendents(root, nodes);
        return nodes;
    }

    private static void addAllDescendents(Parent parent, ArrayList<Node> nodes) {
        for (Node node : parent.getChildrenUnmodifiable()) {
            nodes.add(node);
            if (node instanceof Parent)
                addAllDescendents((Parent)node, nodes);
        }
    }
```

Comment: not quite sure what you mean: the empty space to the right of the column is not a tableCell, but the tableRowCell (and no, you never-ever try to get hold of the cells ;) - handled by its :odd style attribute (which shines through the tableCells as they are transparent). You could try to let the tableCell do the odd-styling and remove it from the tableRow

Comment: @kleopatra thank you for your reply. I don't understand what do you mean that let the tableCell do the odd-styling and remove it from the tableRow. I can neither select those empty cells by css selector nor get the Obeject in my Application. Then how can I change the tableCell to odd-styling?

Comment: have a look at how tableRowCell does it, apply to a custom tableCell if not empty (and carefully read the first sentence in my last comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a CSS stylesheet to apply the styles to remove the background from `TableRowCell`s and instead add the background to the `TableCell`s:

```css
/* overwrite default row style */
.table-row-cell {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
}

/* apply row style to cells instead */
.table-row-cell .table-cell {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-table-cell-border-color, -fx-background;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
}

.table-row-cell:odd {
    -fx-background: -fx-control-inner-background-alt;
}

/* fix markup for selected cells/cells in a selected row */
.table-row-cell:filled > .table-cell:selected,
.table-row-cell:filled:selected > .table-cell {
    -fx-background: -fx-selection-bar-non-focused;
    -fx-table-cell-border-color: derive(-fx-background, 20%);
}

.table-view:focused > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .table-row-cell:filled:selected .table-cell,
.table-view:focused > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .table-row-cell .table-cell:selected {
    -fx-background: -fx-selection-bar;
}
```

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
```

---

**Note:** There are no `TableCell`s outside of existing columns. The background is applied to the `TableRowCell`s.
Also retrieving the cells from a virtualizing control is a bad idea:

- The cells are created during the first layout pass. They may not be present at the time you run your code.
- Interacting with the control (e.g. by resizing it, scrolling it, ect.) may result in creation of additional cells. Any modifications you've done to the cells you found before by traversing the scene are not applied to those new nodes automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is:

```
.table-row-cell:empty {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: The question is about the striping of the remaining space (to the right of the column), that is the row isn't empty